# go - Simple worker pool

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine, worker-pool

As a beginner in go and programming in general, I've been coding a port scanner in go with gopacket library and most of the code is done, but I've been running into a problem of spawning too many goroutines and getting 'read ip4 0.0.0.0: i/o timeout' I've done some research and it seems I need to implement a worker pool I've been trying to implement this example 'https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools' as I'm still learning goroutines and channels I've been at it a few days now and can't seem to figure out how to implement the above example correctly in my program can you guys give me some pointers or preferably a code fix example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/layers"
)

// Get preferred outbound ip and port of this machine
func GetOutboundIPPort() (net.IP, int) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "1.1.1.1:80")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    localAddr := conn.LocalAddr().(*net.UDPAddr)
    return localAddr.IP, localAddr.Port
}

func ipv4_gen(out chan net.IP) {
    ip, ipnet, err := net.ParseCIDR("192.168.0.0/24")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for ip := ip.Mask(ipnet.Mask); ipnet.Contains(ip); inc(ip) {
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        dstaddrs, err := net.LookupIP(ip.String())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        dstip := dstaddrs[0].To4()
        out <- dstip
    }
    close(out)
}

func inc(ip net.IP) {
    for j := len(ip) - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
        ip[j]++
        if ip[j] > 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}

func port_scanner(dstip net.IP) {
    dstport := layers.TCPPort(80)

    srcip, port := GetOutboundIPPort()
    srcport := layers.TCPPort(port)

    ip := &layers.IPv4{
        SrcIP:    srcip,
        DstIP:    dstip,
        Protocol: layers.IPProtocolTCP,
    }
    tcp := &layers.TCP{
        SrcPort: srcport,
        DstPort: dstport,
        Seq:     1105024978,
        SYN:     true,
        Window:  14600,
    }
    tcp.SetNetworkLayerForChecksum(ip)
    buf := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
    opts := gopacket.SerializeOptions{
        ComputeChecksums: true,
        FixLengths:       true,
    }
    if err := gopacket.SerializeLayers(buf, opts, tcp); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.ListenPacket("ip4:tcp", "0.0.0.0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    if _, err := conn.WriteTo(buf.Bytes(), &net.IPAddr{IP: dstip}); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set deadline so we don't wait forever.
    if err := conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        b := make([]byte, 4096)
        n, addr, err := conn.ReadFrom(b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error reading packet: ", err)
            return
        } else if addr.String() == dstip.String() {
            // Decode a packet
            packet := gopacket.NewPacket(b[:n], layers.LayerTypeTCP, gopacket.Default)
            // Get the TCP layer from this packet
            if tcpLayer := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeTCP); tcpLayer != nil {
                tcp, _ := tcpLayer.(*layers.TCP)

                if tcp.DstPort == srcport {
                    if tcp.SYN && tcp.ACK {
                        fmt.Printf("Discovered open port %d/tcp on %s\n", dstport, dstip)
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func worker(id int, ips <-chan net.IP) {
    for ip := range ips {
        go port_scanner(ip)
    }
}

func main() {
    ips := make(chan net.IP)
    go ipv4_gen(ips)

    for w := 1; w <= 10; w++ {
        go worker(w, ips)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new goroutine for each piece of work inside the worker so it defeats its purpose.
You need to run the work instead of starting a goroutine inside the worker.

Comment: So do I just add all the code from port_scanner function to the worker instead of the function?

Comment: That would do it but it’s more than you have to do. You can just call the function instead of starting a goroutine.

Comment: Alright but that still doesn't solve my problem of how to pass the ips channel to the worker function.

Comment: It’s hard to understand your question. You also didn’t say anything about this problem.

Comment: Basically I don't know how to pass the work from the ips channel to the worker pool.

Comment: It seems like the code you posted is doing it. What’s the problem with it?

Comment: The program is running but not doing anything, I've checked wireshark and its not sending tcp packets or giving any errors just runs without any output I presume in an infinite loop.

Comment: It’s actually quite the opposite. In go once main returns the program exits. You need to continue doing something in main until all workers are done. You should read about WaitGroup.

Comment: Well, I just implemented a WaitGroup based on https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups and that got the program running, but still getting 'read ip4 0.0.0.0: i/o timeout'.